# Pass in unique pointer for inherited class to constructor with unique pointer for base class?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to do the following: I have an inherited class B from base class A. I want to create a constructor for a method that takes in a unique pointer to class A but still accept unique pointers to class B, similar to pointer polymorphism.

```
void Validate(unique_ptr<A> obj) {obj->execute();}
...

unique_ptr<B> obj2;
Validate(obj2);
```

This doesn't seem to work as I've written it (I get a `No matching constructor for initialization` error), but I wonder if this is still possible?

Comment: `Validate(std::move(obj2));`

Comment: You can not make a copy of a `unique_ptr`, as its name guarantees.  Pass it by reference `void Validate(unique_ptr<A> & obj)` or pass the raw pointer `void Validate(A* obj)`

Comment: @Frank `Validate(std::move(obj2));` will compile, but it will also destroy the pointed-to object, which I would guess isn't the intention of a function named "Validate".  It would literally _invalidate_.

Comment: @DrewDormann If OP wants `Validate()` to take a non-owning pointer to `A` they should use `Validate(A* obj)`, passing a `unique_ptr<>` by reference is rarely the right thing to do. If `Validate()` takes a `unique_ptr<>`, then that means `Validate()` takes ownership.

Comment: Of two minds on that one because I still live with a maintenance foot in the world of the ownership of all raw pointers needs to be known. Now-a-days raw is taken to mean unowned, but ... people <expletive deleted> up and `unique_ptr<A> & obj` expresses intent beautifully. But so could `A & obj` and a dereference at the call site.

Comment: @user4581301 On the flip-side, in cross-TU code, this also introduces yet another level of indirection, which invalidates the fundamental "unique_ptr has no overhead over raw pointers" property that is often being relied on, especially in mixed/transitioning codebases.

Comment: @user4581301 `unique_ptr<A> & obj expresses intent beautifully` If the intent is to (potentially) modify the unique pointer to point elsewhere, then I agree, because that's the intent that such parameter expresses. If the intent is to access the object, then that's what `A&` expresses.

Comment: Agreed. Omitted a `const` there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue doesn't really have anything to do with polymorphism, but rather how `unique_ptr<>` works in general.

`void Validate(unique_ptr<A> obj)` means that the function will **take ownership** of the passed object. So, assuming that this is what the function is meant to do, you need to handoff said ownership as you call it.

In the code you posted, you would do this by *moving* the existing `std::unique_ptr<>`. This will ultimately (as in not by the call to `std::move()` itself, but the handoff as a whole) null-out the original pointer. That's the whole point of `unique_ptr<>` after all: There can only be one of them pointing at a given object.

```cpp
void Validate(unique_ptr<A> obj) {obj->execute();}

...

unique_ptr<B> obj2;
Validate(std::move(obj2));

// obj2 is now null.
```

By extension, if `Validate()` is not meant to take ownership of `obj`, then it should not accept a `unique_ptr<>` in the first place. Instead, it should accept either a reference or a raw pointer depending on whether `nullptr` is an expected valid value:

Ideally:

```cpp
void Validate(A& obj) {
  obj.execute();
}

...

unique_ptr<B> obj2;
Validate(*obj2);
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
void Validate(A* obj) {
  if(obj) {
    obj->execute();
  }
}

...

unique_ptr<B> obj2;
Validate(obj2.get());
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot copy a unique pointer.

If you wish to transfer the ownership to the `Validate` function, then you must move from the unique pointer:

```
Validate(std::move(obj2));
```

A unique pointer parmeter accepted by `Validate` implies that it takes ownership, but that design sounds odd given the name of the function - but that may be due to missing context.

If `~A` isn't virtual, then you may not use `std::unique_ptr<A>` because it would try to destroy the object through a pointer to the base which would result in undefined behaviour. You could use a custom deleter in such case.

---

If you don't wish to transfer ownership but instead the function should just access the object, then don't use a unique pointer parameter in the first place. Use a reference instead:

```
void Validate(A& obj) {
    obj.execute();
}
```

It doesn't matter whether the caller has a smart pointer or even whether the object is allocated dynamically.

You can use a bare pointer if you need to represent null, but if you don't need it (as is implied by your attempted implementation), then it's better to use reference since being able to avoid checking for null makes it easier to write a correct program.